# Order By not working in Azure Web Document Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query documentdb inside the Azure Web Document Explorer. The problem is Order By doesn't seem to work anymore.

For instance the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE c.type="myType" ORDER BY c.createdDate
```

When queried I get a red alert stating:

```
Failed to get documents. Please try again.
```

If I remove Order By it works fine.
Any idea why it doesn't work anymore to query with Order By?

Comment: Normally when I see questions like this it's usually the fact that you don't have an infinite precision (-1) range index on `createdDate`. The default is a 3-byte hash index which is only good for retrieving documents when you know the value for that field. That said, the behavior for this didn't used to be an error. It simply gave you the wrong order. So, either they changed that, it's different for Document Explorer, or the problem is not the index. I would try adding the -1 precision range index on that field first.

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why it doesn't work anymore to query with Order By?

Order By can be specified only against a property, either **numeric** or **String** when it is range indexed with the Maximum Precision (-1). More detail please refer to [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/documentdb/documentdb-orderby.md)

> You also cannot perform the following:
>
> Order By with internal string properties like id, _rid, and _self (coming soon).
>
> Order By with properties derived from the result of an intra-document join (coming soon).
>
> Order By multiple properties (coming soon).
>
> Order By with queries on databases, collections, users, permissions or attachments (coming soon).
>
> Order By with computed properties e.g. the result of an expression or a UDF/built-in function