# Azure Document DB query with "ORDER BY" stopped working suddenly

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

"Order by" query on Document DB suddenly stopped working on my development environment and is working fine without "Order by"

Here is the query which is not working (Use to work till yesterday and till yesterday it use to return me 70+ documents and now its returning null results(Empty array)):

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Category = 'test' ORDER BY c.StartDate DESC
```

Here is the query which is working(Currently its returning 70+ results and it use to return the same yesterday (which is not the case with the above query which is not working )):

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Category = 'test'
```

Did someone face the similar problem? What can be the solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order By not working in Azure Web Document Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521926/order-by-not-working-in-azure-web-document-explorer)

Comment: No its not. its actually not throwing me an error. its throwing me an empty array(Null results). But the currently working query is returning me more than 70 records.

Comment: Let me also edit my question.

Comment: Now i have edited my question (Added more description in clear format)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. As per the documentations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies

It clearly says

> "The default indexing policy sets "kind=Hash, precision=3" by default.
>   If it is changed into "kind=Range, precision=-1". Order by on string
>   datatype works as expected."

And i found the solution here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/65

Here are few more links that help you know more about Document DB Indexing

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/order-query-results-with-azure-documentdb/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-your-documentdb-indexing-policies-online/

So i have deleted my old collection and created a new one with precision "-1".

Comment: I have a similar issue.  Added the 'kind=Range,precision=1' setting, but sorts still fail (return nothing) when sorting on string data types.  Number types work fine.  Another anomaly is that if some documents have nulls and some have values, sorting on that field only returns the documents with the nulls.

Comment: I did not need to delete my collection to change the value to -1. Why hash is the default option is silly, I spent hours trying to understand why zero documents were coming back if I used a DESC sort.